# Tag: Should [mimic-iii] tag be just [healthcare] or [medical] instead?

Tags: discussion, tags

I expect over time that there will be a proliferation of online databases. There is a Spanish group that is planning on setting up a similar online healthcare database.

My question is should we have a tag like [mimic-iii](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mimic-iii) for this specific one, and thus create one for each "well used" database as it arises, or should they have a tag that is general to the type of data. In this case [medical](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) or [healthcare](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't merge [mimic-iii](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mimic-iii) into either [medical](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) or [healthcare](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare) because the mimic-iii community is using this site as a Q&A forum, instead of hosting their own.

https://mimic.physionet.org/community/contributing/

(Also, I mute the mimic-iii tag.)

Comment: OK. Good call! Thx.

Comment: The link seems broken now, and I can't find a new forum for discussion

Comment: I updated the link